# How to dynamically add tbar in tab bar in ExtJs

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I need to add tbar dynamically in second tab of tabpanel(not want to add items dynamically in tbar but need to add tbar based on some condition otherwise it should bot be added), below is my code:

```
var wind = Ext.create("Ext.Window", {
                        modal: true,
                        scrollable: true,
                        items: [
                            {
                                margin: '0 0 0 10',
                                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                                reference: "MainTab",
                                plain: true,
                                resizeTabs: true,
                                flex: 1,
                                border: 3,
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        title: "Messages",
                                        rootTab: true,
                                        items: [{
                                           // item
                                        }] }, {    
                                        title: "Alarms",
                                        items: [{
                                                 //item,
                                        }],
                                        tbar: // need to add this tbar dynamically
                                        }]
```

I have tried with initComponent using dockedItems but not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fiddle below is using modern but should be similar in classic.
It is just calling the init function on the controller.

[Here is a fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/3978)

[Editor version of fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3978)

Comment: thanks @mcg1103, its working fine, but I need to insert this tbar before any other component. Right now its coming at end/bottom. Voted for the help, please suggest to get it as on top of screen.

Comment: What version of extjs are you using?  and classic or modern toolkit?   Did you set docked: 'top'?

Comment: i am using ext 7, yup i wrote docked : 'top'

Comment: if you are using classic you need to use addDocked() not add() and the property is dock: 'top' not docked: 'top'  When you post questions it is always good to say version and toolkit :-)  I updated the fiddle to use classic.

Comment: thanks its working now, btw i already have ext7 in tags when i asked this question..

Comment: Yeah I saw your tag after I posted my message.

Comment: can you please look in to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64156292/how-to-call-a-function-from-tpl-in-extjs